# Can I generate .PDF without font (.ttf) file with Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am currently generating a .PDF report in Jasper Report Application. One of the fields uses a particular font, which is not installed on my JasperReport Server, and based on some reason, I am not able to download the font (.ttf) or related files on my server.

Can I generate .PDF without font (.ttf) file with Jasper Report?

```
Error Message:

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 

pdfFontName   : SpecialFont.ttf

pdfEncoding   : Identity-H

isPdfEmbedded : false
```

FINDING:

I have installed the font on my computer and tried not to embed the font into the pdf (on the server side) but it is not working. I am expecting to define the pdfFontName, and if the font is installed on user's computer, the PDF can be viewed.

Also, I tried to add "*net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font=true"* in the project file, but also not working.